# Prove the inequality $\frac{27}{4}(x+y)^3 + 27(x^2+xy+y^2)(x+y) \leq (x^2 + xy + y^2 + 3)^3$

Tags: inequality

Let $0 < x \leq y$. Prove that
\begin{equation}
\frac{27}{4}(x+y)^3 + 27(x^2+xy+y^2)(x+y) \leq (x^2 + xy + y^2 + 3)^3
\end{equation}

I was wondering if I can have a Hint as to how to prove this inequality.

Comment: Please include at least one word, outside of the Math, in a MathSE posting's title.  This allows the MathSE reviewer to *right-mouse-click* on the title, to open the posted question in a separate tab of the browser.

Comment: What is the source of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$x^2+xy+y^2 = (x + y)^2 - xy \ge (x + y)^2 - \frac{(x + y)^2}{4} = \frac34(x + y)^2.$$

Letting $x^2 + xy + y^2 = 3p^2$, we have
$x + y \le 2p$.

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{27}{4} \cdot 8p^3 + 27\cdot 3p^2 \cdot 2p \le (3p^2 + 3)^3 $$
or
$$(6p)^3 \le (3p^2 + 3)^3$$
or
$$6p \le 3p^2 + 3$$
which is true.

We are done.

Comment: For the benefit of "dummies" like me who spent some time wondering about the last step, it's equivalent to $(p-1)^2\geq 0$.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Thanks. Or use AM-GM.

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial
$$ 4(x^2 + xy + y^2 + 3)^3-27 (x+y)^3 - 108 (x^2 + x y + y^2)(x+y)$$
in terms of $s=x+y$ and $p=xy$ equals
$$4(s^2 -p+ 3)^3 - 27 s^3 - 108( s^2-p)s$$

We want to show that this $f(s,p)$ is $\ge 0$ in the region $ g(s,p)=s^2 - 4p\ge 0$,$s,p\ge 0$.

Let's check first that $f\ge 0$ on the curve $g=0$. Indeed, after [some](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=4%28s%5E2%20-p%2B%203%29%5E3%20-%2027%20s%5E3%20-%20108%28%20s%5E2-p%29s%2F.p-%3Es%5E2%2F4) [calculations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Factor%5B-108%20s%5E3%20%2B%204%20%283%20%2B%20%283%20s%5E2%29%2F4%29%5E3%5D) we get
$$f(s, s^2/4) = \frac{27}{16} (s - 2)^2 (s^4 + 4 s^3 + 24 s^2 + 16 s + 16)$$

Now, let us show that $f\ge 0$ on the region below the parabola $g=0$. Assume there exists a point $M$, $f(M)< 0$, below the parabola. By continuity, we may assume the $p$ coordinate of $M$ is $\ne 2$. Now, on the parabola above $M$, $f>0$. We conclude that there exists $N$ below the parabola, $f(N)=0$. Now, the set $f=0$ consists of two curves ( connected components), one a closed curve, another open. Indeed, the equation $f(s,p)=0$  in $p$ has for $s$ in some segment, and outside exactly one. At the boundary of the segment the two roots on the closed curve coincide. Now, above the point $(2,1)$ on the parabola $g=0$, the set $f(s,p)=0$ has three points, $(2,1)$ and two more above them. Indeed,
$$f(2,p) = -4 (p - 1) (p^2 - 20 p + 73)$$
Now we see that both of the components of $f=0$ are above the parabola $g=0$ on the vertical $s=2$. $f=0$ and $g=0$ meet only at $(s,p)=(2,1)$. We conclude that $f=0$ cannot reach below $g=0$. We got a contradiction with $f(N)=0$, $N$ below $g=0$.

Note: we used the structure of algebraic curves that are of degree $3$ in one of the variables. If the discriminant in $p$ of $f(s,p)$ is positive on one closed segment then the curve $f=0$ has one closed loop and one open branch. In our case we have the [discriminant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Discriminant%5B4%28s%5E2%20-p%2B%203%29%5E3%20-%2027%20s%5E3%20-%20108%28%20s%5E2-p%29s%2C%20p%5D)
$$\Delta_p f(s,p)=-314928 s^2 4(s^4 - 24 s^2 - 64 s + 144)$$

The expression $s^4 - 24 s^2 - 64 s + 144$ is negative at $s=2$, and
positive at $s=0$ and for large $s$. Since it has at most $2$ positive roots, we conclude it has exactly $2$ roots $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\alpha < 2 < \beta$. Above the interval $[\alpha, beta]$ the curbe $f=0$ has two connected components, a loop and a part of an open branch.

$\bf{Added:}$ I realized using Desmos that the [curve](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jlfaf3szpi) $f(s,p)=0$ is such an interesting curve. Also, what I said above is incorrect, the curve $f=0$ is in fact connected. I guess that changes the argument a bit. Moreover, looking at the picture convinces somebody of the inequality $f\ge 0$ on $g\ge 0$.